# Finding or generating correct filename extensions

Tags: html, jquery, json, loops, filepath

Say I have a JSON Array called 'blogPost' like below:

```
[
    {
    "date" : "2020.11.25", 
    "title" : "Getting help on Stack overflow"
    },
    {
    "date" : "2020.11.18", 
    "title" : "Putting my site together"
    },
...
]
```

and a folder of images with the post date like below:

2020.11.25.jpg, 2020.11.18.png, 2020.11.03.gif, etc ...

I was hoping to bring in, edit, and .append() a template html snippet using my JSON array - the "date" would populate both some text and a file path in the html snippet:

```
<div>
    <img src="blog/images/{date}.{extension}" alt="{date}">
    <h5>{date} - {title}</h5>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$.getJSON( "blog/posts.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index,item) {
            let extension = 'jpg' || 'png' || 'gif';
            $("<div>").load("blog/blog-snippet.html", function() {
                $(this).html($(this).html().replaceAll("{date}", item.date));
                $(this).html($(this).html().replaceAll("{title}", item.title));
                $(this).html($(this).html().replaceAll("{extension}", extension)); 
                $("#content").append($(this).html());
            });
        });
 });
```

The idea was to use "date" from the array multiple times just to slim and automate the process.

I can change the name of each text and image file using the looped array. However is there a way to generate the correct file extension (jpg, png, etc...) for each image file using html or js/jquery? My current extension variable doesn't find the "correct" extension - it just uses jpeg. This results in only some of the correct file paths.

I suppose my other option would be to add an "image" option to the JSON Array and include the correct file extension.

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: If you have the name of the file including the extension already, why do you need to generate the correct extension again? The problem would be clearer if you could add the relevant code to the question, including the input you have and the output you want to create

Comment: I assume this is directory reading question. You can't do that with jquery alone you need some server side and server side language (PHP, Python, Javascript Node.js, Java,..)